# Apostrophe in SQL Server Free-Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a Full-Text Index where I used to be able to search on "avignon" and get back a result using CONTAINS for a term such as "Les demoiselles d'avignon".

That search no longer works unless I specifically include the apostrophe, such as "d'avignon".  Is this something that I can set within the index?  Did it change with SQL Server 2014?  I upgraded the server and did not notice it until just now.

Comment: are you specifying the correct language id (1036 for French) within the `CONTAINS` predicate?

Comment: Most words are English. This happens to be an exception, although we have a lot of these exceptions.

Comment: can you check the language id of the full text index? Is it English or French?

Comment: It seems that building the index with the Neutral language 0 is the way to solve this.  If you want to post an answer https://stackoverflow.com/users/5857386/andrews I'll mark it as solved b/c it was your comment  that got me thinking about it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added the answer per your request. Will appreciate accept and vote up :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check what language was used in the Full Text Index for the column referenced in `CONTAINS`:

```
select ftc.name as 'Full Text Catalog', ftcols.column_id, ftcols.language_id, ftl.name as 'Language' 
from sys.fulltext_catalogs ftc
   join sys.fulltext_indexes fti on fti.fulltext_catalog_id=ftc.fulltext_catalog_id
   join sys.fulltext_index_columns ftcols on ftcols.object_id=fti.object_id
   join sys.fulltext_languages ftl on ftl.lcid=ftcols.language_id
where ftc.name='FTS_Catalog_Name' -- as seen in SSMS under DB_Name->Storage->Full Text Catalogs
```

The above query should produce result similar to below:

[image: FTS Languages per column]

Then, per OP comment, you need to change the language of the relevant column to `Neutral (LCID=0)`:

```
alter fulltext index on table_name disable
alter fulltext index on table_name drop (fts_column_name)
alter fulltext index on table_name add (fts_column_name LANGUAGE 0 )
alter fulltext index on table_name enable
```

HTH